# How to use "pessimistic" Couchbase locking with the C API?

Tags: c++, c, couchbase, pessimistic-locking

This is incredibly frustrating... I'm using the Couchbase v3 C API, and I ran into a problem that would be solved perfectly by using their "pessimistic" locking. After much effort I believe I've finally figured out how to lock records using it (with `lcb_cmdget_locktime()`, which presumably takes a parameter in microseconds), but I can't figure out how to *unlock* the record once I'm done with it, other than by letting it time out, which isn't an acceptable solution.

The documentation provides one example, [here](https://docs.couchbase.com/c-sdk/current/howtos/concurrent-document-mutations.html#pessimistic-locking), but for some unknown reason it's in Javascript instead of C (!!!), and the concepts don't map to the C API.

Does anyone know how to unlock a pessimistic lock, or have any example C/C++ code using that API? Barring that, does anyone know where to find the source code for any of the non-C APIs that use the C one, since I should be able to work it out from there? (I haven't been able to locate any of those either, not sure they're open-source.)

Comment: I'm not a C developer, but you might be able to find some help in the SDK reference here: https://docs.couchbase.com/sdk-api/couchbase-c-client/group__lcb-store.html

Comment: (Also, I will try to help get that page fixed/updated)

Comment: Thanks, @MatthewGroves. I haven't found the C client documentation to be very usable, I'm sorry to say... I haven't found any way to search it, or any page that includes all of the function names in one place, so I have to poke around to try to find the functions I'm looking for, which takes far too long to be useful.

Comment: (I did find some info in it, with the help of a search engine, but it's not very clear on this subject.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thank you for question

Time in seconds, note that the server might reset time to default, if it larger than maximum time (both durations are configurable). The following command will help to discover effective values for the feature.

```
$ cbstats -u Administrator -p password  localhost all | grep ep_getl
ep_getl_default_timeout:                               15
ep_getl_max_timeout:                                   30
```

To lock the key, one must use get operation with and set lock time using `lcb_cmdget_locktime` and capture CAS value in case of successful lock, for instance like this

```
struct my_result {
    lcb_STATUS status{LCB_SUCCESS};
    uint64_t cas{0};
};

static void get_callback(lcb_INSTANCE *instance, lcb_CALLBACK_TYPE, const lcb_RESPGET *resp)
{
    my_result *res = nullptr;
    lcb_respget_cookie(resp, (void **)&res);
    res->status = lcb_respget_status(resp);
    if (res->status == LCB_SUCCESS) {
        lcb_respget_cas(resp, &res->cas);
    }
}
```

It is good idea to put get with lock code into loop

```
uint64_t locked_cas{0};
int retries = 3;
while (retries > 0) {
    std::string document_id{"foo"};
    my_result result{};
    lcb_CMDGET* cmd = nullptr;
    lcb_cmdget_create(&cmd);
    lcb_cmdget_key(cmd, document_id.c_str(), document_id.size());
    lcb_cmdget_locktime(cmd, 5);
    lcb_get(instance, &result, cmd);
    lcb_cmdget_destroy(cmd);
    lcb_wait(instance, LCB_WAIT_DEFAULT);

    if (result.rc == LCB_SUCCESS) {
        locked_cas = result.cas;
        break;
    } else if (result.rc == LCB_ERR_DOCUMENT_LOCKED || result.rc == LCB_ERR_TEMPORARY_FAILURE) {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(100));
        --retries;
        continue;
    } else {
        std::cerr << "Unexpected issue during get with lock: " << lcb_strerror_short(result.rc) << "\n";
        break;
    }
}
```

Once the key got locked, the update operation might be performed, but keep in mind that it MUST use `locked_cas`, otherwise mutation operation will fail.

```
std::string document_id{"foo"};
std::string new_value{"new value"};
lcb_CMDSTORE* cmd = nullptr;
lcb_cmdstore_create(&cmd, LCB_STORE_REPLACE);
lcb_cmdstore_key(cmd, document_id.c_str(), document_id.size());
lcb_cmdstore_value(cmd, new_value.c_str(), new_value.size());
lcb_cmdstore_cas(cmd, locked_cas);
lcb_store(instance, nullptr, cmd);
lcb_cmdstore_destroy(cmd);
lcb_wait(instance, LCB_WAIT_DEFAULT);
```

To unlock key you also need `locked_cas`, or just wait until server will unlock the document automatically.

```
std::string document_id{"foo"};
lcb_CMDUNLOCK *cmd = nullptr;
lcb_cmdunlock_create(&cmd);
lcb_cmdunlock_key(cmd, document_id.c_str(), document_id.size());
lcb_cmdunlock_cas(cmd, locked_cas);
lcb_unlock(instance, nullptr, cmd);
lcb_cmdunlock_destroy(cmd);
lcb_wait(instance, LCB_WAIT_DEFAULT);
```

Comment: Thank you! It was driving me nuts, not having any decent documentation.